# Android Kotlin How to Test Subscriptions

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I know many similar questions. But none of them have helped. I am wanting to test the subscription setup but it does not work. How do you test it? I have followed the below steps. When I press the button nothing happens, I have added some debugging messages and on button click it returns that Purchase Item Not Found, from the InitiatePurchase method.

1. I have added library to build.gradle (app) file

   ```
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1'
   ```
2. I have enabled billing in android manifest

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
   ```
3. I have setup the subscription logic in a fragment as per the abundant documentation

   ```
    class PremiumFeaturesFragment : Fragment(), PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    var purchaseStatus: TextView? = null
    var purchaseButton: Button? = null
    private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_premium_features, container, false)

        purchaseStatus = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.purchase_status) as TextView
        purchaseButton = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.purchase_button) as Button

        purchaseButton!!.setOnClickListener {
            purchase(rootView)
        }

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext())
            .enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build()
        billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    billingClient!!.queryPurchasesAsync(INAPP) { queryResult, purchases ->
                        if (queryResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                            if (purchases.isNotEmpty()) {
                                handlePurchases(purchases)
                            } else {
                                savePurchaseValueToPref(false)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
        })

        //item Purchased
        if (purchaseValueFromPref) {
            purchaseButton!!.visibility = View.GONE
            purchaseStatus!!.text = "Purchase Status : Purchased"
        }
        //item not Purchased
        else {
            purchaseButton!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            purchaseStatus!!.text = "Purchase Status : Not Purchased"
        }

        return rootView
    }

    private val preferenceObject: SharedPreferences
        get() = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0)

    private val preferenceEditObject: Editor
        get() {
            val pref: SharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0)
            return pref.edit()
        }

    private val purchaseValueFromPref: Boolean
        get() = preferenceObject.getBoolean(SUBSCRIBE_KEY, false)

    private fun savePurchaseValueToPref(value: Boolean) {
        preferenceEditObject.putBoolean(SUBSCRIBE_KEY, value).commit()
    }

    //initiate purchase on button click
    fun purchase(view: View?) {
        //check if service is already connected

        if (billingClient!!.isReady) {
            initiatePurchase()
        }
        //else reconnect service
        else {
            billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(requireContext()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build()
            billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        initiatePurchase()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error " + billingResult.debugMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }

                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {}
            })
        }
    }

    private fun initiatePurchase() {

        println("initating purchase entered")
        val skuList: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID)
        val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(INAPP)

        billingClient!!.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build())
        { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                println("initating purchase entered 2")

                if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    println("initating purchase entered 3")

                    val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0])
                        .build()
                    billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), flowParams)
                } else {
                    println("initating purchase entered 4")

                    //try to add item/product id "purchase" inside managed product in google play console

                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Purchase Item not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                println("initating purchase entered 5")

                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),
                    " Error " + billingResult.debugMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(billingResult: BillingResult, purchases: List<Purchase>?) {
        // If item newly purchased
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            handlePurchases(purchases)
        }
        //if item already purchased then check and reflect changes
        else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
            billingClient!!.queryPurchasesAsync(INAPP) { _, alreadyPurchases ->
                if (alreadyPurchases != null) {
                    handlePurchases(alreadyPurchases)
                }
            }
        }
        //if purchase cancelled
        else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Purchase Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        // Handle any other error msgs
        else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error " + billingResult.debugMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


    fun handlePurchases(purchases: List<Purchase>) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            //if item is purchased

            if ((purchase.skus.contains(PRODUCT_ID)) && purchase.purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                if (!verifyValidSignature(purchase.originalJson, purchase.signature)) {
                    // Invalid purchase
                    // show error to user

                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error : Invalid Purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return
                }
                // else purchase is valid
                //if item is purchased and not acknowledged


                if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                    val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                        .build()
                    billingClient!!.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, ackPurchase)
                }
                //else item is purchased and also acknowledged
                else {
                    // Grant entitlement to the user on item purchase
                    // restart activity

                    if (!purchaseValueFromPref) {
                        savePurchaseValueToPref(true)
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Item Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        requireActivity().recreate()
                    }
                }
            }
            //if purchase is pending
            else if ((purchase.skus.contains(PRODUCT_ID)) && purchase.purchaseState == PurchaseState.PENDING) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),
                    "Purchase is Pending. Please complete Transaction", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            //if purchase is refunded or unknown
            else if ((purchase.skus.contains(PRODUCT_ID)) && purchase.purchaseState == PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE) {
                savePurchaseValueToPref(false)
                purchaseStatus!!.text = "Purchase Status : Not Purchased"
                purchaseButton!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Purchase Status Unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    var ackPurchase = AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener { billingResult ->
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            //if purchase is acknowledged
            // Grant entitlement to the user. and restart activity

            savePurchaseValueToPref(true)
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Item Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            requireActivity().recreate()
        }
    }


    /**
     * Verifies that the purchase was signed correctly for this developer's public key.
     *
     * Note: It's strongly recommended to perform such check on your backend since hackers can
     * replace this method with "constant true" if they decompile/rebuild your app.
     *
     */
    private fun verifyValidSignature(signedData: String, signature: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            // To get key go to Developer Console > Select your app > Development Tools > Services & APIs.

            val base64Key = "LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE IS PUT HERE (ACTUAL KEY IS HERE IN LIVE CODE)"
            Security.verifyPurchase(base64Key, signedData, signature)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            false
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (billingClient != null) {
            billingClient!!.endConnection()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val PREF_FILE = "MyPref"
        const val SUBSCRIBE_KEY = "subscribe"
        const val PRODUCT_ID = "com.ManageIt.manageit.premium"
    }
   ```

   }
4. I have added a subscription to the google play store
   [image]

Please let me know what other information is required to provide assistance. I have spent weeks trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Anywhere you query the purchase make sure you use SUBS, not INAPP. INAPP is for in app products not subscriptions. Easy fix :)